# Connect my checkboxes with dynamic tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have created a list with some items and a checkbox for each item like such:

```
    <md-list ng-controller="ListCtrl" class="listControls">

    <md-list-item ng-repeat="account in accounts">
    <md-checkbox ng-model="account.selected" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(account.title) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(account.title)"></md-checkbox>
    <p>{{account.title}}</p>        
    </md-list-item>

    </md-list>
```

My controller is in a file named **list.js**:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.config(function($mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider){
    $mdIconProvider
        .defaultIconSet('img/icons/sets/core-icons.svg', 24);

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('red')
        .accentPalette('red');
    })

.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.accounts = [
    {id: 1, title: "Account A", selected: false},
    {id: 2, title: "Account B", selected: false},
    {id: 3, title: "Account C", selected: false},
  ];
...
```

And inside here I have a function that lets me act whenever one of the checkboxes state changes.

What I was hoping to do is add dynamic tabs that will appear when an item is selected and disappear otherwise.

I tried adding the tabs as seen in the angular material site, and saved the javascript code in a file named **tabs.js**.

My problem is that the tab creation function is in tabs.js, and the function that reacts when a checkbox is changed is inside list.js, and thus in different controllers.

How can I connect those two functions, or if this is not doable, or advisable, then what  would be the best way for me to achieve what I want?

**EDIT1**

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzNKy) is what I am trying to do without the tabs.js that I want to integrate.

Comment: You can use $rootScope

Comment: Can you provide a link to specific angular site from where you downloaded the code of tabs.js? Can you modify this code or are you using it as a library function? If so, you can for example just publish particular methods using $scope, use events, watchers etc. depending on situation

Comment: @leo.fcx I could not find much on rootScope, and simply calling it throws an error. Do you have an example for that?

Comment: @mpasko256 I simply copied it from the example on dynamic tabs here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Services` for data sharing between controllers.
See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

See this code snippet which adds/removes tabs based on whether the corresponding checkbox is checked or not. I am using `dataSrvc` for sharing data between `listCtrl` and `tabsCtrl`

```js
angular.module('materialApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])

.service('dataSrvc', [function() {
 var tabData = {
  tabs: [
   {
    'id': 1,
    'label': 'One',
    'selected': true
   },
   {
    'id': 2,
    'label': 'Two',
    'selected': true
   },
   {
    'id': 3,
    'label': 'Three',
    'selected': true
   },
   {
    'id': 4,
    'label': 'Four',
    'selected': true
   },
  ]
 };
 return tabData;
}])

.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataSrvc', function($scope, dataSrvc) {
 $scope.items = dataSrvc.tabs;

 $scope.exists = function(item) {
  return $scope.items.indexOf(item) > -1;
 };

 $scope.toggle = function(item) {
  item.selected = !item.selected;
 };
}])

.controller('tabsCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataSrvc', function($scope, dataSrvc) {
 $scope.tabs = dataSrvc.tabs;
}]);
```

```css
.ma-tabs {
 width: 400px;
}

.ma-tab-content {
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="materialApp">
 <section ng-controller="listCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <md-checkbox ng-checked="item.selected" ng-click="toggle(item)">
    {{ item.id }}
   </md-checkbox>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section ng-controller="tabsCtrl">
  <md-tabs class="ma-tabs">
   <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
        ng-if="tab.selected"
     label="{{::tab.label}}">
     <md-content class="ma-tab-content">
      Tab {{::tab.label}} Content
     </md-content>
   </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very interesting answer, especially  for successfully explaining to me what services are.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should take care to attach all controlers to the same module

```
angular.module('yourModuleName', ...)
```

As I can see in your code, ListCtrl is higher level in angular controllers hierarchy than controller for tabs (I recognize it looking into html code). So everything put into a scope in ListCtrl will be visible in lower controllers.

If I were in your place I would create an empty JS object {} in ListCtrl scope

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.tabCtrlMethods = {};
```

and then attach required methods in tabs controller.

Comment: I will try to apply your suggestions and get back at you hopefully when I make it. Thanks.

Comment: Does your second suggestion imply that I should scrap my tabs.js code and merge the its functions with my ListCtrl, so everything is under one controller?

Comment: No, I only suggest to publish methods from tabs.js in a way visible in ListCtrl. The code still might be in two different controllers. See: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-models-between-nested-controllers.html

Comment: Interesting link but I dont think I can apply it. If you look at the codepen link on my question you will notice that when I click a checkbox I execute a function that decides if it was selected or no. I do not know any other direct way. And because my tab creation function must be called from inside there, I cant do what you are suggesting.